# How can I catch a timeout request

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

This is my code:

```
properties.service.ts

get(stringParams) {
    let headers = new Headers({
      "X-AUTH-APIKEY":  API_KEY
    });

    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });
    return this.http
      .get(`${API_URL}/properties/?${stringParams}`, this.options)
      .timeout(50)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  }



posts.ts

    this.propertiesService.get(arrayParams).subscribe((data: any) => {

    }), (err) => { console.log("timeoout")};
```

I put 50 in my timeout so is fired but i cannot catch the error in this way

```
}), (err) => { console.log("timeoout")};
```

I get this error :

```
TimeoutError {name: "TimeoutError", stack: "TimeoutError: Timeout has occurred↵    at new Time…http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)", message: "Timeout has occurred"
```

EDIT:

```
this.propertiesService.get(arrayParams).subscribe((data: any) => {

        }), (err) => { console.log("timeoout")};

get(stringParams) {

    return this.http
      .get(`${API_URL}/properties/?${stringParams}`, this.options)
      .timeout(50)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) { 
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

I tried this solution but i still get this error[image]

SOLUTION:

The code should be like this(the err inside the subscribe) :

```
}, (err) => { console.log("timeoout")});
```

Comment: so you are not getting a response within 50ms that you have set.. what error are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting the console.log("timeoout") but i get the error that i describe above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`err` should inside `subscribe`

```
this.propertiesService.get(arrayParams).subscribe((data: any) => {

    }, (err) => { console.log("timeoout")});
```

You should `catch` the exception :

```
get(stringParams) {

    return this.http
      .get(`${API_URL}/properties/?${stringParams}`, this.options)
      .timeout(50)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any) { 
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Comment: @FrancoCoronel I can't see the image in SO because of the restriction of the Internet in my company. But can you move the par err like my answer pls? Because it can cause the problem. Your part err is outside the subscribe

Comment: You are right i have the err outside the subscribe that was the error. Thank you